# npm package doesn't use latest after update or install

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm pretty sure this is an easy question -but I can't find any documentation on SO, or the web. I'm using `npm` to update my version of `cordova` and `phonegap`, but everytime I do an `npm update`, it's still using the old version.

```
XXXXXX: XXXXX$ phonegap -v
3.2.0-0.17.1
XXXXXX: XXXXX$ npm update -g phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
XXXXXX: XXXXX$ phonegap -v
3.2.0-0.17.1
```

I've even tried a force reinstall (it's still the same version):

```
XXXXXX: XXXXX$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
/Users/XXX/.nvm/v0.10.26/bin/phonegap ->    /Users/XXXX/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
phonegap@3.4.0-0.19.18 /Users/XXXX/.nvm/v0.10.26/lib/node_modules/phonegap
XXXXXX: XXXXX$ phonegap -v
3.2.0-0.17.1
```

However if I use sudo to find the version - I get the right one:

```
XXXXXX: XXXXX$ sudo phonegap -v
3.4.0-0.19.18
```

Is this normal or do I need to run all `phonegap` commands as `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you installed the latest for root, but not the local user. Try `npm install -g phonegap` (without sudo).

Answer (score 0):

you have two phonegap versions installed in your system.i suggest you remove all versions and reinstall phonegap to latest version.if you dont want to do this try running all commands as sudo if using sudo(running as root) is making use of the latest version alone..although i suggest remove and reinstall because two versions of phonegap may cause errors when installing plugins